# Add missing years to data frame (reshaping)

Tags: r

Say I have data frame as follow:

```
df <- structure(list( 
year = c(2001, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003),
name = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
revenue = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 30, 40, 50)),
.typeOf = c("numeric", "factor", "numeric"),
row.names = c(NA, -7L),
class = "data.frame")
```

First column contains years, second - names and last one - revenues. As you might see the company "A" contains data only for the first year, while the rest companies have more data. I want yo add new rows for company "A" with `NA` as a revenu for next years (i.e. 2002 and 2003). For this purpose I use follow code:

```
df %>%
spread(year, revenue) %>% 
gather(year, revenue, 2:ncol(.)) %>% 
arrange(name) %>% 
View()
```

It works pretty good, especially for a small data sets, however I am not sure that my solutions is correct from programming point of view. Probably exists much better solution using `melt`, `cast(dcast)` or something else. Any ideas?

**EDITED: any ideas how can I do it in/using pipe "%>%" ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `data.table` you can use `dcast()` to cast to wide, meanwhile creating a complete groupset using `drop = FALSE` (which keeps empty groups).

```
setorder( dcast( setDT(df), year + name ~ ., drop = FALSE ), name )[]

#    year name  .
# 1: 2001    A 10
# 2: 2002    A NA
# 3: 2003    A NA
# 4: 2001    B 20
# 5: 2002    B 30
# 6: 2003    B 40
# 7: 2001    C 30
# 8: 2002    C 40
# 9: 2003    C 50
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use `expand.grid` of `unique` *name* and *year* and `merge` them to your `df` using `all=TRUE`.

```
merge(expand.grid(lapply(df[2:1], unique)), df, all=TRUE)
#  name year revenue
#1    A 2001      10
#2    A 2002      NA
#3    A 2003      NA
#4    B 2001      20
#5    B 2002      30
#6    B 2003      40
#7    C 2001      30
#8    C 2002      40
#9    C 2003      50
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[CJ(year, name, unique = TRUE), on = c("year", "name")]

#    year name revenue
# 1: 2001    A      10
# 2: 2001    B      20
# 3: 2001    C      30
# 4: 2002    A      NA
# 5: 2002    B      30
# 6: 2002    C      40
# 7: 2003    A      NA
# 8: 2003    B      40
# 9: 2003    C      50
```